# How can I create variable controls at runtime?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, compact-framework, .net-assembly

I'm trying to create controls at runtime using Reflection.
In my case, I get a string like Label or Button and I would like to create a object Label or Button of it.

```
Assembly WinFormasm = Assembly.Load("System.Windows.Forms,Version=2.0.000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089");

Control label = (Control)Activator.CreateInstance(WinFormasm.GetType("System.Windows.Forms."+type));
```

When I execute this, I get the error:

> File or assembly name 'System.Windows.Forms,Version=2.0.000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089', or one of its dependencies, was not found.

I don't realy know what is wrong there. I have also tried:

```
try
{
    Type cntrl = Type.GetType("System.Windows.Forms.Button,System.Windows.Forms, Culture=neutral, Version=2.0.0.0, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089", true);
    label1.Text += cntrl.ToString() + " ";
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    label1.Text += e.ToString() + " ";
}
```

Trying this, I got an execution error: he can't create the type and returns `null`. If I change the gettype string into `System.Int32`, it works.

How can I create a control item using a string?

Comment: Please consider using spell check to assist you in writing your questions. Many web browsers provide it as a built-in feature, like Google Chrome and Mozilla Firefox. It's a great way to catch the simple mistakes that make your question difficult to understand.

Comment: If you're just loading from `Windows.Forms` a switch statement might be easier, but you are maybe loading from unknown assemblies too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your version number is wrong for System.Windows.Forms:

```
var assembly = Assembly.Load("System.Windows.Forms, version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089");
```

Then to create the desired control type, just specify the type name:

```
var type = "Button";
var control = (Control)Activator.CreateInstance(assembly.GetType("System.Windows.Forms." + type));
```

Comment: the LoadWithPartialName is deprecated and also not supported in de compact .net framework

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I've changed it back to using Load.

Comment: got the same error as in the early version File or assembly name 'System.Windows.Forms, version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089', or one of its dependencies, was not found.

Answer (score 2):

What's wrong with the following?

```
Button cntrl = new Button();
```

If you're hardcoding the values why do you need to use reflection?

Comment: Maybe he is developing something like Xaml,Creating UI from file. Why post meaningless answer?

Comment: @Stecya: Hardly a "meaningless" answer. This wouldn't be the first time that someone tried to do something in a very complicated way that could be done much more simply.

Comment: The question states that the program receives a string like "Button" or "Label" and he needs to create the right control based on that string. So it isn't hard-coded.

Comment: i dont know the type i get a string wich can be everything: "button", "label", "ListBox" etc.
Jon gets the point

Comment: He is hardcoding the assembly and namespace, so there are a fixed number of control types that can be instanciated.

Comment: Or perhaps he write a simple text case to prove his point. I agree: This answer is useless.

Answer (score 0):

to create the controls from string 
you need to use `Activator` class 
check this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.createinstance.aspx)

Comment: check [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.aspx)[/link]

Comment: I am using tyhe compact framework wich doesn't supprt the createinstanse(string string variant) only the createinstanse(Type) variant. the onely problem is to get the type right this keeps returning null.

Comment: i had this error before so I tricked it by making ownclass 
class MyButton : System.Windows.Forms.Button
{
    
}

now 
Type t= Type.GetType("WindowsApplication.MyButton");

Answer (score 0):

http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/236152-how-create-control-instance-dynamicly-text had a quite intesting idea to solve the problem with a little fix it worked for me.

I get the type of form (controls are standing in a form right) from that type I get the assembly.
From the assembly I get the object by calling the `gettype` function with the parameters of the type of control I would like.
Finally I cast it to a control type.

```
private Control createcontrol(string type)
{
    Type typen = typeof(Form);
    Assembly assem = typen.Assembly;
    //Assembly assem = Assembly.LoadFrom(typeof(Form).ToString());
    Type controlType = assem.GetType("System.Windows.Forms."+type); // GetType(controlType);
    object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(controlType);
    Control control = (Control)obj;
    return control;
}
```

Thanks for the help folks!

Answer (score 0):

```
        string ControlType = "TextBox";

        Assembly FormAssembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Form));
        Control MyControl = (Control)FormAssembly.CreateInstance("System.Windows.Forms." + ControlType);
```

Just change `ControlType` value.